# One single number to date and hour format in R

Tags: r, datetime

I need help to convert a column wich contains the date in one number like 20160317000043, and put it into format 2016/03/17 00:00:43 (or the date and hour in different columns).
I searched a lot, but I couldn't find how to do this: `as.date` is for string dates, but I have a number, and it is no delimiter between date and hour!

I'm sorry if the question it's not in the proper format. I'm learning how to do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You could convert the number to character, and run `strptime` on it:

```
d <- 20160317000043
strptime(as.character(d), "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
# [1] "2016-03-17 00:00:43 CET"
```